# How bubbling up of mouse over works in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a rectangle with column span 2 and, a label and a button in a grid row.

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Rectangle>
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Product Two</Label>
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button2_Click">Select</Button>
```

I intend to change the fill color of the rectangle when mouse over on the row occurs. But it seems mouse over on label or button prevents mouse over on the rectangle, unlike HTML.

Is this the default behavior? Whats the right approach?

Edit, Full XAML for the grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources >
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#44000000"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>            
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold">Product</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">Choose</Label>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Rectangle>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Product One</Label>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button1_Click">Select</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please show us the `grid` these 3 items are within.

Comment: Added full xaml for the grid

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want to accomplish can be solved by replacing the rectangle with a `Grid` outlining your other items.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold">Product</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">Choose</Label>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#44000000"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Product One</Label>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Select</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

There are some other stuff i want to change with this xaml but that is not part of your problem.

Let me know if this is giving the result you want.

Comment: I want to change the background of a single row. This answer changes the background of the whole grid.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I stopped at one row to shorten the code. Actually, I have eight of them. So a grid for every row, right? Do we still need the column definition in the parent grid?

Comment: What i would do now is using SharedSizeGroups, so you set the outer most Grid to Grid.IsSharedSizeScope = "True", then in the ColumnDefinition you set the SharedSizeGroup = "<Name>", so in the Child grids you dont have to re-define the sizes but just say: SharedSizeGroup = "<Name>", so you could control the column sizes by just changing them at one location. Furthermore you might also take a look at ListView as it seems to me you are trying to recreate its behaviour.

Comment: @Spongebrot could you try edit my answer to fit with your suggestions? This SharedSizeGroups is new to me and i can't seem to make it work, or atleast not how i intent it to.

Comment: @MikeHjortChristensen My bad, forgot SharedSizeGroup does not work with Star annotations but only with Auto or fixed sizes :/